# jQuery ajax success error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form witch sends an email:

**JS**

```
var that = $(this);
$.ajax({
  url: '../wp-content/themes/bsj/php/validate.php',
  type: 'post',
  context: that,
  data: $('#sign-up').serialize(),
  cache: false,
  success: function(){ 
    alert('success!');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('error!');
  }
});
```

**PHP**

```
/*----------------------------------
    Variables
----------------------------------*/

    // Personal info
    $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $dept = $_POST['dept'];

    // Contact details
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $ext = $_POST['ext'];
    $fax = $_POST['fax'];

    // Job Summary
    $job_title = $_POST['job_title'];
    $positions = $_POST['positions'];
    $hours = $_POST['hours'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $wage = $_POST['wage'];
    $wage_type = $_POST['wage_type'];
    $job_description = $_POST['job_description'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];


/*----------------------------------
    Mail Form
----------------------------------*/

    $to      = 'email@email.com';
    $subject = 'Subject';
    $headers = 'From: noreply@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: noreply@email.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $message = 
        '### Personal Information ###' . "\r\n\r\n" .
        'Prefix: ' . $prefix . "\r\n" .
        'First Name: '. $first_name . "\r\n" .
        'Last Name: ' . $last_name . "\r\n" .
        'Company: ' . $company . "\r\n" .
        'E-Mail: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
        'Title: ' . $title . "\r\n" .
        'Dept.: ' . $dept . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= 
        '### Contact Details ###' . "\r\n\r\n" .
        'Address: ' . $address . "\r\n" .
        'Address 2: ' . $address2 . "\r\n" .
        'City: ' . $city . "\r\n" .
        'State: ' . $state . "\r\n" .
        'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n" .
        'Ext.: ' . $ext . "\r\n" .
        'Fax: ' . $fax . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= 
        '### Job Description ###' . "\r\n\r\n" .
        'Job Title: ' . $job_title . "\r\n" .
        'Positions: ' . $positions . "\r\n" .
        'Hours: ' . $hours . "\r\n" .
        'Age: ' . $age . "\r\n" .
        'Wage: ' . $wage . ' - ' . $wage_type .  "\r\n" .
        'Job Description: ' . $job_description . "\r\n" .
        'Comments: ' . $comments;

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I'm setting `that` because I'm using a modal window plugin to display the form, this way I get the right scope.

The main problem is that when I click submit the email gets in my inbox just fine but it always executes the error function and not the success one.

This is driving me nuts, I looked EVERYWHERE for answers with no luck.

I got the success callback a couple times but now it doesn't work anymore and I don't know why. I'm getting the email just fine...

I checked the response headers with Chrome Developer tools and I get `200 OK` so it's getting back. What is the problem?

**EDIT:** Well, I give up for today after 5 hours trying. I might come back tomorrow and try other things. I'll just use `complete` for now, which works fine. I'm thinking it could be related to the server. The client is using IIS...

Comment: have you checked in the firebug for any errors?

Comment: You should post your actual code. May be there are some hidden issues not noticeable by you.

Comment: The jQuery.ajax error callback has additional parameters which may help troubleshooting. Change your error callback to error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) and alert the 'textStatus' and 'errorThrown' variables to see what they contain.

Comment: `textStatus = 'error'` and `errorThrown = (empty)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not provide your `validate.php` code so I'm confused. You have to pass the data in JSON Format when the mail is successful.
You can use [json_encode();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) PHP function for that.

Add `json_encode` in validate.php at last

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
```

JS Code

```
success: function(data){ 
     if(data.success == true){ 
       alert('success'); 
    }
```

Hope it works

Comment: I just added it to the original question

Comment: But how does that explain that I was able to get the success callback before and not now? I disabled cache thinking that was the problem but still get error, but the email gets sent just fine.

Comment: mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));

JS Code
 success: function(data){ 
                    if(data.success == ture){
alert('success');
}

Hope it works
                },

Comment: try to add 
dataType: 'json'
in
$.ajax

Comment: Can you post you new code again... in jsfiddle or somewhere else

Answer (score 3):

Try to set response dataType property directly:

```
dataType: 'text'
```

and put

```
die('');
```

in the end of your php file.
You've got error callback cause jquery cannot parse your response. In anyway, you may use a "complete:" callback, just to make sure your request has been processed.

Comment: This didn't work either. Still get error but email gets sent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem;

```
textStatus = 'error'
errorThrown = (empty)
xhr.status = 0
```

That fits my problem exactly. It turns out that when I was loading the HTML-page from my own computer this problem existed, but when I loaded the HTML-page from my webserver it went alright. Then I tried to upload it to another domain, and again the same error occoured. **Seems to be a cross-domain problem. (in my case at least)**

I have tried calling it this way also:

```
var request = $.ajax({
url: "http://crossdomain.url.net/somefile.php", dataType: "text",
crossDomain: true,
xhrFields: {
withCredentials: true
}
});
```

but without success.

**This post solved it for me:** [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)