# AJAX: how to compare variable in ajax from php data success or error message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried many example from stackoverflow.com 
[jQuery ajax success error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059489/jquery-ajax-success-error)

I pick code from this examle
[image]

but always gives me error.

whenever i run below code if ajax code error then ajax shows error message but when php have error code ajax always show **success: function ( data )** code.

as i know **data.status == 'success'** not comparing from php so my code gives error

**i know this question is duplicate but i saw all questions from stackoverflow these not resolve my problem so i post again**

**please help**

**AJAX CODE**

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('.contactf').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (!contactvalid())
                return false;
            $(this).find(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
            $('#gif').css('display', 'block');
            var form = $(this);
            var post_url = 'contactmail1.php';
            var post_data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: post_url,
                data: post_data,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == 'success') {
                        alert(data);
                    } else if (data.status == 'error') {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('failed client side');
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

//
header('Content-type: application/json');

if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST' ) {

    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $name = $_POST[ 'Name' ];
    $email = $_POST[ 'Email' ];
    $phone = $_POST[ 'number' ];
    $sub = $_POST[ 'contact_subject' ];
    $msg = $_POST[ 'Message' ];


    if ( !( isset( $_POST[ 'Name' ] )and isset( $_POST[ 'Email' ] )and isset( $_POST[ 'number' ] )and isset( $_POST[ 'contact_subject' ] )and isset( $_POST[ 'Message' ] ) ) ) {
        echo "Some Field is Blank";
    } else {


        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->setFrom( $email, $name );


        $mail->addAddress( 'mail@gmail.com', 'Inderjeet' );

        $mail->Subject = 'Mail from site';

        $mail->msgHTML( '<html><body><table border=0 width=554><tr><td colspan=2><p><b>Enquiry from Contact Page Thorsoncne.com</b><br><br></p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=2 class=text4>FORM submitted at ' . date( 'd F Y h:i:s A' ) . '<br></td></tr>   
<tr><td width=200 class=text3>Name :</td><td class=text3>' . $name . '</td></tr>   
<tr><td>Email Id :</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>   
<tr><td>Phone/Mobile :</td><td>' . $phone . '</td></tr>   
<tr><td>Subject :</td><td>' . $sub . '</td></tr>   
<tr><td>Message :</td><td>' . $msg . '</td></tr>   
</table></body></html>' );

        if ( !$mail->send() ) {


            $response_array['status'] = 'failed';
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            echo json_encode($response_array);

        } else {
            $response_array['status'] = 'success';
            echo json_encode($response_array);
            echo "Query Submitted";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `echo "Query Submitted";` after `echo json_encode($response_array);`

Comment: dont use screenshots, copy the code into the question please

Comment: And JSON encode `"Some Field is Blank";` or use $response_array['status'] = 'blank';

Comment: And add `dataType: "json"` to the post

Comment: you have to encode the whole response, not just bits of it, otherwise the final result that comes back to the client will not be valid JSON. The strings you're currently outputting directly via "echo" need incorporating into the encoded object instead (or removing, if they're superfluous). You didn't say what error it's giving you but I guess its something about invalid JSON.

Comment: Read and reply on @B.Desai comment

Comment: If you look in your browser's network tab (in the dev tools) to examine the ajax request, you can easily see the response and whether it's valid JSON or not. Yours will be part JSON and part raw string, which confuses the browser, it doesn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: @B.Desai i removed all echo from php (excluding echo json_encode($response_array); ) now alert show [object object]

Comment: so now your code working. if you want to alert message then do `alert(data.status);`

Comment: @B.Desai Very Big Thanx to you its work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Java script code - Add `dataType: "json"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('.contactf').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!contactvalid()) return false;
      $(this).find(":submit").prop("disabled", true);
      $('#gif').css('display', 'block');
      var form = $(this);
      var post_url = 'contactmail1.php';
      var post_data = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: post_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: post_data,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.status == 'success') {
            alert(data);
          } else if (data.status == 'error') {
            alert(data);
          }
        },
        error: function(data) {
          alert('failed client side');
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And Remove `echo "Query Submitted";` after echo `json_encode($response_array);`

Comment: In AJAX response use `alert(data.status);` to print response.